# Session cookie doesn't work in the server but work in localhost

Tags: node.js, azure, cookies, express

I'm using the package `cookie-session` to store some data. My issue is that in localhost everything works but when deploy the application on azure, the following object isn't retrieved correctly. I know that the question is too broad but I need that someone says his thoughts about this. I'm totally sure that there isn't a bug because the same code in localhost works while in the server not. Maybe the following object isn't storable?

```
object = [
    [
      "Plaid Savings (9606)",
      {
        "routing": "021000021",
        "account": "9900009606"
      }
    ],
    [
      "Plaid Checking (1702)",
      {
        "routing": "021000021",
        "account": "9900001702"
      }
    ],
    [
      "Plaid Premier Checking (5204)",
      {
        "routing": "021000021",
        "account": "9900005204"
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Here how it is configured:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'sess',
    keys: [config.session.secret],
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
}));
```

Comment: How have you configures `cookie-session`? What do you mean by _"isn't retrieved correctly"_? Etc...

Comment: sorry. I'm going to explain better. it isn't retrieved correctly means that is undefined.

Comment: Do you see the cookie actually being set in your browser? In other words, is it present in the response headers?

Comment: Yes it is set correctly

Comment: did you check if the middleware is being installed with deployment?

Comment: @Mazzy Are you configure an external session state provider? Azure need it.

Comment: The problem is not related at all to the the session. Consider the question resolved.